# How to make SVG components resize using react drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

Thanks in advance, Right now am using React DND to enable drag and drop function for svg shapes in a container. I would like to resize any shape using mouse (Dragging from any of 4 sides). How do I accomplish this feature using React Drag and Drop library. As I learned I have understood only moving contents are possible using React Drag and Drop. I also tried to use the Library *React Re Resizable* in Drag and drop. But since the components deals with SVG library, Resizable library doesnt work.

Is there any work around for this issue, Or anything React Library for resizing shapes/svg components.

Below is the sandbox url and code

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Resizable } from "re-resizable";

const style = {
  background: "#f0f0f0"
};

const App = () => (
  <svg>
    <Resizable
      style={style}
      defaultSize={{
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      }}
    >
      <rect height={200} width={200} />
    </Resizable>
  </svg>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));


https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-liskov-hcq75?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
```

Comment: Can you please mention your code here and expected output wrt code?

Comment: const App = () => (
  <svg>
    <Resizable
      style={style}
      defaultSize={{
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      }}
    >
      <rect height={200} width={200} />
    </Resizable>
  </svg>
);

Comment: I need to work the Resizable inside the SVG tag

Comment: Try to work on this way: https://codesandbox.io/s/easy-use-drag-inl4h?file=/src/DragTest.js